# How can I re-use a QueryRunner connection?

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

I have a web application, and I create the `DataSource` with the parameter `poolSize: 10`. And I created a QueryRunner Object to query something in every HTTP request, then I called `.release()` method before response send. But when 8 times HTTP requests after, the whole node app will get blocked. New HTTP request will be pending forever until I restart the app or mysql.

```js
async function _createConnection () {
    ...
    let ds = new DataSource({
        ...
        poolSize: 10,
    })
    ds = await ds.initialize()
    dataSource = ds
    return ds
}

let count = 0

export class MysqlClient {
    public connection!: DataSource
    public session!: QueryRunner

    public constructor () {
        this.connection = dataSource
        this.session = this.connection.createQueryRunner()
    }

    public async connect () {
        await this.session.connect()
        this.session.startTransaction()
        return this
    }

    public async release (): Promise<void> {
        try {
            if (!this.session.isReleased) {
                count++
                logger.info('QueryRunner Release count ==>', count)
                await this.session.release()
            }
        } catch (err) {
            logger.error(err)
            throw err
        }
    }
}
```

I am using `node v16.6.2` and `typeORM 0.3.12`(which is the latest). I don't know what is wrong in my code, any help will be appreciated

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well I found where is the problem here ...

It is very silly, I ignored that the browser will try access to the endpoints with `OPTIONS` method  before actual starting a real HTTP request.

And I used a middleware like this:

```
export const requestInterceptor = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
    ...
    req.db = await new MysqlClient().connect()
    next()
}
```

So it didn't get released properly in every `OPTIONS` request, just changes to code below solved problem.

```
if (req.method !== 'OPTIONS') {
    req.db = await new MysqlClient().connect()
}
```